# Use a button with different sub items in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this issue, and I'm having a mental block.
But anyways,
I'm using a template from **Bootstrap** to develop my .Net application, and in this particular template they've got kind of like [image]

> so on client's click, it shows the different sub levels/items.

But when I try to use the same code, it just doesn't show the sub items, I don't know if it's because of the Css (which I haven't deleted anything), or if it's because of some syntax that you can't use in Asp.net..

This is the code:

```
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-1">
            <em class="fa fa-navicon">&nbsp;</em> Multilevel <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-1" class="icon pull-right"><em class="fa fa-plus"></em></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="children collapse" id="sub-item-1">
                <li><a class="" href="#">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right">&nbsp;</span> Sub Item 1
                </a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right">&nbsp;</span> Sub Item 2
                </a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right">&nbsp;</span> Sub Item 3
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Sorry if it's such a dumb question, but I have got learn somehow.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Hugo.

Comment: Are you sure the CSS is being loaded? If something is inhibiting their visibility, my first guess is missing CSS...next, failing javascript or jQuery code that presumably should be toggling the visibility of the classes

Comment: Hey @DavidW, thanks for your time. I checked it, and it's all there.

Comment: Your code is fine. See https://jsfiddle.net/4va86k08/2/ I think @DavidW is right. Might be bootstrap missing?

Comment: When I launch it in visual studio, it doesn't work, also I checked it again, it's all there. Thanks for your answer @less :)

Comment: When you say "launch it in visual studio" do you mean you're using the debugger and viewing your page through a browser or are you looking at the page designer view

Comment: Yes, @abney317, I'm doing developing a dynamic web site trough  asp.net. And the code does seem to be fine but it's not working inside visual studio

Comment: Are you viewing your page in an actual web browser? Sorry, you didn't quite answer my original question with "yes" haha

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! I am debugging it on Firefox

Comment: Your code looks fine though like others said. Try using F12 to see the developer tools (in Firefox) and look at the console for any errors (if you haven't already)

Comment: I have and it's giving some errors on the js file actually

Comment: !function ($) {
    $(document).on("click","ul.nav li.parent > a ", function(){          
        $(this).find('em').toggleClass("fa-minus");      
    }); 
    $(".sidebar span.icon").find('em:first').addClass("fa-plus");
}

(window.jQuery);
 $(window).on('resize', function () {
  if ($(window).width() > 768) $('#sidebar-collapse').collapse('show')
})
$(window).on('resize', function () {
  if ($(window).width() <= 767) $('#sidebar-collapse').collapse('hide')
})